# Trying to position subplots next to each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to position two subplots next to each other (as opposed to under each other). I am expecting to see [sp1] [sp2]
Instead, only the second plot [sp2] is getting displayed.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

x = [0, 1, 2]

pyplot.figure()

# sp1
pyplot.subplot(211)
pyplot.bar(x, x)

# sp2
pyplot.subplot(221)
pyplot.plot(x, x)

pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 3 numbers are rows, columns, and plot #.  What you're doing is respecifying the number of columns in your second call to subplot, which in turn changes the configuration and causes pyplot to start over.

What you mean is:

```
subplot(121)  # 1 row, 2 columns, Plot 1
...
subplot(122)  # 1 row, 2 columns, Plot 2
```

Comment: That would display them under each other, not next to.

Comment: I just realize that you probably meant:
subplot(121)
subplot(122)
Thanks for your response

Answer (score 5):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

x = [0, 1, 2]

pyplot.figure()

# sp1
pyplot.subplot(121)
pyplot.bar(x, x)

# sp2
pyplot.subplot(122)
pyplot.plot(x, x)

pyplot.show()
```