# How do I plot an image and a graph side by side?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, fig

I am trying to plot an image with its respective histogram side by side with equal proportion using `plt.fig()` in Python but I am not getting the desired output. Instead I get the *histogram* overlapping onto the image.

Any idea as to why this keeps happening?

```
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np


img = np.uint8(mpimg.imread('motherT.png'))
im2 = np.uint8(mpimg.imread('waldo.png'))
# convert to grayscale
# do for individual channels R, G, B, A for nongrayscale images

img = np.uint8((0.2126* img[:,:,0]) + \
        np.uint8(0.7152 * img[:,:,1]) +\
             np.uint8(0.0722 * img[:,:,2]))

im2 = np.uint8((0.2126* img[:,:,0]) + \
        np.uint8(0.7152 * img[:,:,1]) +\
             np.uint8(0.0722 * img[:,:,2]))

# show old and new image
# show original image
fig = plt.figure()

plt.imshow(img)
plt.title(' image 1')
plt.set_cmap('gray')

# show original image
fig.add_subplot(221)
plt.title('histogram ')
plt.hist(img,10)
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im2)
plt.title(' image 2')
plt.set_cmap('gray')

fig.add_subplot(221)
plt.title('histogram')
plt.hist(im2,10)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Perhaps this helps: [Trying to position subplots next to each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616427/trying-to-position-subplots-next-to-each-other)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be doing this for two images? Subplots would be your best bet. The following shows you how to use them for a `2 x 2` effect:

```
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np


img = np.uint8(mpimg.imread('motherT.png'))
im2 = np.uint8(mpimg.imread('waldo.png'))

# convert to grayscale
# do for individual channels R, G, B, A for nongrayscale images

img = np.uint8((0.2126 * img[:,:,0]) + np.uint8(0.7152 * img[:,:,1]) + np.uint8(0.0722 * img[:,:,2]))
im2 = np.uint8((0.2126 * im2[:,:,0]) + np.uint8(0.7152 * im2[:,:,1]) + np.uint8(0.0722 * im2[:,:,2]))

# show old and new image
# show original image
fig = plt.figure()

# show original image
fig.add_subplot(221)
plt.title(' image 1')
plt.set_cmap('gray')
plt.imshow(img)

fig.add_subplot(222)
plt.title('histogram ')
plt.hist(img,10)

fig.add_subplot(223)
plt.title(' image 2')
plt.set_cmap('gray')
plt.imshow(im2)

fig.add_subplot(224)
plt.title('histogram')
plt.hist(im2,10)

plt.show()
```

This would give you something like:

[image: matplotlib screenshot of 2x2 usage]

Also note, in your original code, your grey scale calculation for `im2` was using the image data for `img` not `im2`.

You might want to turn the axis off for each of your images, to do this you could add `plt.axis('off')` before each `plt.imshow()` giving you:

[image: without axis]

Comment: Martin Evans thanks for your answer, it works just fine. My question is, Is there a way to adjust the subplot so the image and histogram size appear bigger? I changed the values of **add_subplot** but that made some weird changes to the image and histogram(at times the histogram was inverted and the image stood the same and vise versa).

Comment: If you mean the overall figure size, just change it as follows: `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 20))`