# Matplotlib pyplot putting two plots side by side

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Hi I'm trying to put two plots side by side with plt and have tried the recommendations here: [Trying to position subplots next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616427/trying-to-position-subplots-next-to-each-other)

however I am plotting using the default capabilities from pandas by doing

```
myDataFrame.plot(kind='scatter' x='xcol', y='ycol')
```

so i can't do `plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)` as in `myDataFrame.subplot(2,1,2)` (obviously)

and doing

```
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
myDataFrame.plot(kind='scatter' x='xcol', y='ycol') 

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
myDataFrame.plot(kind='scatter' x='xcol', y='ycol')
```

just adds two plots before the plot i want

any ideas how i can still use `myDataframe.plot(kind='scatter')` and put two of them side by side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `DataFrame.plot` takes an `ax` argument for a pyplot axis https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html. 
Try:

```
ax = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
myDataFrame.plot(kind='scatter' x='xcol', y='ycol', ax=ax)
```

Comment: very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 5):

In case you are still looking for it, here is a minimal working answer for you (excluding imports)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10,4))

df = pd.DataFrame([[5.1, 3.5, 0], [4.9, 3.0, 0], [7.0, 3.2, 1],
                [6.4, 3.2, 1], [5.9, 3.0, 2], [7.1, 4.5, 2]],
                columns=['X', 'Y', 'value'])
df.plot.scatter(x='X', y='Y', c='red', ax=ax[0])
df.plot.scatter(x='X', y='Y', c='red', ax=ax[1])
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help